# Get difference in seconds between selected and right now date and time in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, time, duration

How to get duration between selected time (using graphical date and time picker) and date and time now in seconds?

Both methods `getSelectedDate()` and `getSelectedTime()` look fine, selected date and time is fine. But there is something wrong with the method `getCountDuration()`. The value is incorrect. And I can't find an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    int YEAR = 0, DATE = 0, MONTH = 0, HOUR = 0, MINUTE = 0;
    Button dateButton;
    TextView dateTextView, timeTextView, textViewDateAndTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dateButton = findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
        dateTextView = findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        timeTextView = findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);

        textViewDateAndTime = findViewById(R.id.textViewDateTimeDuration);

        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getSelectData();
                getSelectTime();
                getCountDuration();
            }
        });
    }

    public LocalDate getSelectData() {

        final Calendar calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        YEAR = calendarDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        MONTH = calendarDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        DATE = calendarDate.get(Calendar.DATE);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int date) {

                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

                String dateText = DateFormat.format("dd.MM.yyyy", calendar1).toString();

                dateTextView.setText(dateText);
            }
        }, YEAR, MONTH, DATE);

        datePickerDialog.show();
        return null;
    }

    public LocalTime getSelectTime() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final LocalDateTime nowIs = LocalDateTime.now();
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");//("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
        final LocalDateTime dateTime = currentDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

        HOUR = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        MINUTE = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        boolean is24HourFormat = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);

        final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onTimeSet: " + hour + minute);
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                String dateText = DateFormat.format("hh:mm", calendar1).toString();
                timeTextView.setText(dateText);
                String dateNowText = formatter.format(dateTime).toString();
            }
        }, HOUR, MINUTE, is24HourFormat);

        timePickerDialog.show();
        return null;

    }

    public void getCountDuration() {
        final Calendar setDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        setDate.set(YEAR, MONTH, DATE, HOUR, MINUTE, 0);
        long subs = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - setDate.getTimeInMillis();
        textViewDateAndTime.setText(subs + " duration in milliseconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and its friends `Date` and `Calendar`. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: After converting the whole code to LocalDateTime, the date and time picker is working but the method getCountDuration(), not. Extra some errors like that:  java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0 The upper code is legacy but stable.

Comment: Your date picker confusingly numbers the months from 0 for January through 11 for December. `LocalDate` uses the way humans use, from 1 through 12. So you need to add 1 when constructing the `LocalDate`.